# Want to know if there is a way to find all the globally installed packages in pycharm

Tags: python

I want to know a way to see all globally installed packages of python in pycharm.
Also i need to find a way to import all the globally installed packages using pip on the cmd to the new virtual environments that i have created using "virtualenv" in the cmd.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/ specifically look at the [examples](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/#examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view all the installed packages in pycharm by clicking on **View-->Tool Windows-->Python Packages.** This will show you the whole list of dependencies installed.

To use all the dependencies of one virtual environment in the other one, you can use pip freeze command. Use **'pip freeze > requirements.txt'**. This will store all your dependencies into the **'requirements.txt'** file. Now to install these dependencies into the other virtual environment you can use **'pip install -r requirements.txt'**. This will install all packages in one shot(without the need of installing every package separately).
Hope I answered all your questions :)